Build RNN from scratch with using only Dense layers and Sequential?
I'm intending to build RNN from scratch using only keras Dense layers and Sequential model? Is that possible at all? If we unfold RNN, it's just a sequence of a unique dense layer repeated over and over just with different outputs. How to implement such thing using only  keras Dense layers and Sequential model?
I'm really stuck at this and wondering if this is possible at all :(
This is the best I've come up so far:
def buildRNN(hidden_state_size, input_size, L=2, final_layers=None):    
    inputs = [None] * (L + 1)

    # h_0 = zero vector
    inputs[0] = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(hidden_state_size,), name='h_0')    
    last_output_layer = inputs[0]

    feed_back_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(
            hidden_state_size, 
            activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid, name=f'feedback')

    for i in range(1, L + 1):
        input_layer = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(input_size,), name=f'i_{i}')
        inputs[i] = input_layer

        concat_layer = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([input_layer, last_output_layer])
        last_output_layer = feed_back_layer(concat_layer)

    for layer in final_layers:
        last_output_layer = layer(last_output_layer)

    return tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=last_output_layer)

This gives maximum recursion depth exceeded
